# No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm trying to make a `JUnit` tests for the first time for a basic class, but I can't seem to get my tests running. I've been looking for answers, but none of them seem to work for me.

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals; 
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;  
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;  

public class TestBaseballGameTest {     
   String team1 = "Yellow Jackets";     
   String team2 = "Dawgs";  
   BaseballGame arena = new BaseballGame(team1, team2);     

   @Test    
   public void testConstructor() {       
      assertEquals("Yellow Jackets", arena.getName(0));       
      assertEquals("Dawgs", arena.getName(1));    
   }     
}
```

[JUnit error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTOos.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here. If it's possible, also provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way we can help better; otherwise, it's not really clear what you're asking or what is your problem.

Comment: Please show how you've written any code of your test(s).  The error message states that no tests is found with JUnit 5.

Comment: What IDE are you using, what is your build system (maven, gradle etc), which version of junit you are using. Also show us your code.

Comment: `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestBaseballGameTest {

 String team1 = "Yellow Jackets";
 String team2 = "Dawgs";
 BaseballGame arena = new BaseballGame(team1, team2);

   @Test
   public void testConstructor() {
      assertEquals("Yellow Jackets", arena.getName(0));
      assertEquals("Dawgs", arena.getName(1));
   }
   
}`

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, but I don't know what build system I'm using. I'm using jUnit 5.

Comment: How you run your Test?